# How to do Load Test for ASP.NET MVC with a fixed number of user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

Here is a situation: In our company, we are building `3 ASP.NET MVC + 2 SharePoint applications` then deploy to a server farm. Let call them: `MVC1, MVC2, MVC3, SP1, SP2.`
Now the requirement is that, each application will have a number of user:

- MVC1 (100),
- MVC2 (200),
- MVC3 (50),
- SP1 (400),
- SP2 (250).

Question is: How to do Load Test for all above applications and make sure they can serve those number of user?

We are using Load Test in Visual Studio 2013 but we are having an issue:

- During 10 minutes, if TestScenario1 of MVC3 runs too fast then there will be 1000 tests performed. But TestScenarios2 of SP1 runs too slow then just 10 tests are performed. It's not correct because there are 400 users are using SP1, but only 50 users for MVC3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the solution by doing test distribution in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are testing for N num of concurrent users, but you didn't mention if all your apps are running on 1 box or load balanced on multiple boxes. In typical load test, there should be some metrics that you need to measure in order to conform to your [SLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_level_agreement).

Are testing for percentage of dropped requests or meeting 3 seconds response time?

Either way, i suggest using the free and widely used [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) or apache bench for [multiple URLs](https://code.google.com/p/apachebench-for-multi-url/)

Comment: Let assume MVC1, MVC2, MVC3 will be installed to Server1. SP1, SP2 will be on Server2. Each scenario has it own "Response Time Goal". The question is that: How to simulate the reality of 100 users for MVC1... For example: 100 users are using MVC1, then just 40 customers will be created by 20 users. So the maximum test for CreateCustomer scenarios is 40.